# Find min value in a HashMap of custom objects, where the map contains 2 entries with the same min values

Tags: java

I encountered this really weird edge case - I'm writing some Java 11 code to find the min object in a HashMap where the map entry is like this:

```
Map.Entry<String,MyCustomObject>
```

This is a simple problem and all works fine except this one corner case that I encountered - when the HashMap contains 2 objects with the same min value - the one returned can vary from one execution to the next!

```
return myMap.entrySet()
            .stream().min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(MyCustomObject::getValue)))
            .get().getKey();
```

What seems to be happening is that on each execution the order that the Map entries are being streamed through can vary and this is causing the effect where the result can vary when the map contains 2 entries with the same min value (I was able to write a simple unit test to catch this issue).

What I want is to always return the same min object (the last one encountered) every time the code is run? Thanks

Comment: One of the first sentences in the HashMap JavaDoc reads: "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time." - So not having a guaranteed order is kind of what you have to accept if you work with a HashMap

Comment: Currently the code is returning the *first* one encountered, because that's how `min()` works. The problem is that the encounter order changes, because a `HashMap` is an **unordered** collection.

Comment: Can you define your 'min' more precisely thank `getValue`? Maybe another feature of the object if getValue doesn't work. Maybe use `thenComparing` on another feature.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that a `HashMap` doesn't store its keys in any particular order.

It seems that you're looking for a map that you can traverse in insertion order.  Try using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.  It's a map that is always traversed in the order in which its keys were initially inserted.